# Is it possible to make pycharm's run display section display the same as actually running the program would?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Disclaimer: Sorry if the question is stupid or repeated, I've tried to find similar ones that answer what I need to know but I couldn't. I've started to learn programming about 1 month ago and this is my second time on this website. Feel free to point out any errors or better ways to formulate my questions on stackoverflow, I'll be grateful.

---

Context:
I was trying to find out a way to print a string - in this case `' º '` - after my user's input - an angle -, on the same line.

I need an alternative way to do this, or help with the one I'm using.

What I got from my research is that, apparently, using the command `os.system(cls)` should erase the previous line, and putting `\033[A` before the string should move the cursor up one line. So using these two together should erase the previous line and then overwrite it.
Here's my try:

```
from os import system
cls = lambda: system('cls')
angle = float(input(f'Insert an angle:'))
cls()
print(f'\033[AInsert an angle:{angle}º')
```

Desired result on run:

```
Insert an angle: *60*º # being 60 the user's input
```

Actual result on pycharm:

```
Insert an angle:60
Insert an angle:60.0º #  for some reason, you can't see it when paste it here, but there's a symbol of a crossed rectangle on the beginning of this line on Pycharm's run
```

How it looks on pycharm's run terminal
[image: How it looks on pycharm]

As you can see, the line isn't getting overwritten, only repeated.
What is weird is that when I run this program with Python 3.8 instead of Pycharm, it works as intended, but, on Pycharm, the line isn't overwritten. Instead, Pycharm just prints a crossed rectangle symbol.

Why does it work when executing the file with Python 3.8, but not when pressing "run" on pycharm?
Is there a way to avoid it?
Are there better alternatives to printing a string on the same line as an input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases where I need special printing (ANSII escape codes, backspacing...), I use the actual Terminal, not the Python Console.

[image]

For whatever reason, interactive consoles, regardless of IDE, seem to have issues with handing specialties like that. With the normal Terminal, it works as expected:

[image]

I have never found a way of having the interactive console handle cases like this.